# Proof of hairy ball theorem: is it correct/complete? Generalizable?

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-fields

Here is an attempt at a proof of the hairy ball theorem, that I'm not sure is quite right: Suppose we had a non-vanishing continuous tangent vector field on $S^2$. Then it's clear the tangent bundle of the circle would be trivial (you can make consistent coordinate frames everywhere by scaling your vector field to unit length and taking a vector rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise as your frame), and thus its circle bundle would be trivial as well, being $S^2 \times S^1$, with fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$. But the circle bundle is acted on transitively and without fixed points by $SO(3)$, so it is homeomorphic to $SO(3)$, which has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Is there anything subtle I could be missing here? I'm not that practiced with bundles, so I want to be sure. If this does work, how hard is it to generalize to higher dimensions? I think I prefer this proof to others that I have seen: can this argument be found somewhere else?

Comment: It is correct but incomplete as the part about topology of $SO(3)$ is missing the proof. The proof does not generalize to higher dimensions.

Comment: I'm confident in that part. There is no way to analyze SO(4) in a similar way to generalize?

Comment: The claim about SO(3) is correct. But trivializing the tangent bundle will fail if all you have is just one vector field. BTW, $S^3$ and  $S^7$ are parallelizable.